# Does a CNOT quantum gate violate no cloning theorem?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization, superposition

I am a curious quantum computing learner. :)

Once observe the CNOT gate:
[image]

as you can see there it converts a |+> to |-> in the top or to say in another way it clones the |->

state. So does this violate "No Cloning Theorem".

Say for example when you apply a CNOT gate to a qubit in superposition then that is indeed as the

same as cloning the qubit in superposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Cloning* means you have a unitary transforming $U$ that takes $|\psi\rangle|0\rangle $ to the $|\psi\rangle|\psi \rangle $ for ***all*** *quantum states* $|\psi\rangle$. That is,

$$ U\big(|\psi\rangle|0\rangle \big)  = |\psi\rangle|\psi \rangle \hspace{0.5 cm} \forall \ |\psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H} $$

where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space. Thus, what you  shown is not a violation of the *no cloning theorem*.

Note that the no-cloning theorem tells us that it is **impossible** to clone a specific *unknown* quantum state, but it **does not preclude** the construction of a known quantum state from a known quantum state.